# Can Liquibase process csv data with no quotes

Tags: liquibase

I have a CSV file with the following format that I'd like to load to a DB2 database with Liquibase's loadData feature:

`2,92551,1,Nature of Service / Procedure,1`

(Notice no quotes anywhere)

I'd like Liquibase to treat the 1st, 3rd, & 5th column as INTEGERS and the 2nd & 4th column as STRINGS.

My column definition is as follows:

`columns:
          - column:
              name: uid
              type: NUMERIC
          - column:
              name: hcpcs_cpt_code
              type: STRING
          - column:
              name: mue_value
              type: NUMERIC
          - column:
              name: mue_edit_rationale
              type: STRING
          - column:
              name: metadata_uid
              type: NUMERIC`

Liquibase us wrapping all of the columns in single quotes and causing the insert to fail:

`[INFO] INSERT INTO "XXXXX".MUE_NCCI_EDIT("2", "92551", "1", "Nature of Service / Procedure", "1") VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

resulting in

`Error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: "2" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.22.29`

Is my CSV just plain stupid or is there a Liquibase config I'm missing?

I've tried various combinations of `separator` and `quotechar` combinations with no luck.

Comment: The attribute is called `quotchar` (without the 'e').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer, for me at least, was to add a header row to the csv file i.e.:

`uid,hcpcs_cpt_code,mue_value,mue_edit_rationale,metadata_uid 
2,92551,1,Nature of Service / Procedure,1`

This combined with the header attr. on the column definition resolved the issue:

        `columns:
          - column:
              name: uid
              type: NUMERIC
              header: uid
          - column:
              name: hcpcs_cpt_code
              type: STRING
              header: hcpcs_cpt_code
          - column:
              name: mue_value
              type: NUMERIC
              header: mue_value
          - column:
              name: mue_edit_rationale
              type: STRING
              header: mue_edit_rationale
          - column:
              name: metadata_uid
              type: NUMERIC
              header: metadata_uid`

I think the error messages/documentation could have been clearer here. I only resolved through a process of trial and error.